# Administration System rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am not using a plugin and used instead the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters for my administration. However the issue I am having is the following

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy
```

What I would like also is if you are admin_user to then be able to edit, and update the customer. But because of correct_user been used, It doesn't work

I have try the following

```
def correct_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_customer?(@customer) || customer.admin?
end
```

But then I have an undefined customer. What would be my best approach to allow the user if admin to modify a selected customer.

The error occurs if i click the a customer#edit (not me)

```
NameError in CustomersController#edit

undefined local variable or method `customer' for #<CustomersController:0xa51fd60>
Rails.root: /home/jean/rail/map
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you've meant

```
redirect_to(root_path) unless current_customer?(@customer) || @customer.admin?
```

Comment: It does works, however now if i change myself to a normal user, i am also qualify has an admin. Why?